# How To Adjust The Pagefile Size In ReactOS?

Tags: pagefile, reactos

[image: Page File]

I want to use a different page file size, but it doesn't seem to accept my commands. There is a pagefile present; I can see it in my root directory. The "memory" command also shows stats for it. How do I change the size? I'm using ReactOS 0.3.15.

Comment: Questions about bugs in pre-release/beta software or prototype hardware are off-topic. Bugs in pre-release products are common and even expected, and are often fixed before the final version is released — at which point the question becomes obsolete. Consider reporting these types of problems directly to the product manufacturer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time Advanced Settings does list the ability to adjust the size of the pagefile but the implemenation doesn't
appear to be finished so it doesn't work. You do have a pagefile.sys in your root directory, and if you type "memory" 
into the commandline you will see skewed information about how big your pagefile is. You can adjust the page file size 
by creating a registry entry for it. This is may damage your installation so proceed at your own risk!

Steps:

[image]

1) In ReactOS, open the command prompt, and type "memory" to see the current size of your pagefile.

[image]

2) Boot up a Parted Magic live-cd (or whatever Linux distro you pefer). Mount the drive with ReactOS installed on it,
and check to see how big your pagefile actually is.

3) Boot up ReactOS, open Regedit, and browse to "`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management`"

[image]

4) Under Windows there would normally be entry here for the pagefile, but ReactOS doesn't have one. Right click, and
choose "new", choose type "Multi-String Value", and name it "PagingFiles". Double click on the new item, and in the 
"Value data" section type "c:\pagefile.sys " followed by your desired size values for initial size, and max size with
a space seperating them. For example "`c:\pagefile.sys 1024 1024`" will give a 1GB pagefile. Click "OK", and then restart
the computer, and boot up ReactOS so the resize can take place.

[image]

5) In ReactOS, open the command prompt, and type "memory". You will see the values, while still skewed, have changed.

[image]

6) Boot up a Parted Magic live-cd (or whatever Linux distro you prefer), and check the pagefile.sys to veryify it's new
size compared to the old.

Notes:

- ReactOS only supports ext2, and FAT filesystems. FAT has file size limit of 4GB.
- Tested, and working as of September 8th 2014 on ReactOS 0.3.15.